# how to integrate angular web with google sign in

Tags: angular, google-signin

I am new to google cloud platform. I do not find any code solution for this, I want to implement google sign in my angular web, can any one suggest me any documentation, blogs for angular, i tried with  this package (npm install --save angularx-social-login) but, this package is depercated

Comment: Just use @angular/fire maybe?

Comment: can you please  share any working code examples or code snippets related to @angular/fire

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://www.positronx.io/full-angular-firebase-authentication-system/?amp

Comment: can i use this in production environment?

Comment: Yes you can, is production grade.

Comment: yes, firebase working fine. Thank You @MikeOne

Answer (score 1):

In file `index.html` you can add library

```
    <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

In file `component.html` you can add btn sign in with google

```
      <div id="buttonDiv"></div>
```

In file `component.ts` you can follow me at fuction in AfterViewInit()

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: "Client_ID",
      callback: (response) => {
        //handle response in here
      }
    });
    google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
      { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
    );
    google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
  }
```

If you have error declare, you can declare in file `component.ts`

```
declare var google: any;
```